# is there a way to pass the value to another page?

Tags: php

in `a.php` I do:

```
$a = "hello,world";
$_POST['a'] = $a;
```

in `b.php`, i want to get `$a` value, when i `echo $_POST['a']`, there is no value output. how do i do?

Comment: Sessions! Maybe. What's the actual situation? What do `a.php` and `b.php` do, and what's the nature of the value you need to pass?

Comment: i want to pass the procduct image src to another page, if using session,how do ido? could you give me an example. many thanks

Comment: @learning - Detailed info on session in my answer ! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Page **a.php**:

```
<?php
session_start();
$a = "hello,world";
$_SESSION["name_anything"] = $a; // This will store $a value to the session
//here i've given session name "name_anything"
?>
```

Page **b.php**:

```
<?php
session_start(); //you need to initiate the session using this function
//You need to session_start() on every page on which you want to use session.
//Even on the page on which you are storing the session.
echo $_SESSION["name_anything"]; //this will print the value of $a
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$_SESSION[]`.

Here is an example:

```
$_SESSION['a'] = $a;
```

and use it in `a.php`

Answer (score 1):

This is not how you post information to another page, you need to use a form for that, or another alternative is to use a GET request, or to use the session.

Try reading this, or other php articles.
http://mrarrowhead.com/index.php?page=php_passing_variables.php

Answer (score 1):

This would be the HTML form in a.php:

```
<form action="b.php" method="post" >
<input type="text" name="poster" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

In b.php, you can put some PHP to echo out the data

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

echo $_POST['poster']; 


}
```