# pass value to another page in php

Tags: php, html

I have a log in page that I want to pass a value to from another page... but it wont pass can anyone help me? please.

login page code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php 
   ob_start();
   session_start();
   include('include/connect.php');

?>

<html>
   <head>
      <title>test</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <form action="" method="post">
         <input type="text" name="username">
         <input type="text" name="password">
         <input type="submit" name="login" id="send" />
      </form> 
   </body>
</html>

<?php
   // Inialize session
   if(isset($_POST['login'])){
      $username=$_POST['username'];
      $password=$_POST['password'];
      $repcode=$_POST['repcode'];
      // Include database connection settings
      include('connection.php');
      // Retrieve username and password from database according to user's input
      $login = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' and password = '$password'");

      // Check username and password match
      if (mysql_num_rows($login) == 1) {
         // Set username session variable
         $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
         $_SESSION['repcode'] = $_POST['repcode'];
         // Jump to secured page
         $stat = "UPDATE users SET status='login'";
         mysql_query($stat);    
         header('Location: home2.php');
       }else {
       }
    }
?>
```

page to be passed:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php 
   ob_start();
   session_start();
   include('include/connect.php');

?>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>test</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <form method="get">
         <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $_POST['username']; ?> "/>
         <input type="text" name="repcode" value="<?php echo $_POST['repcode']; ?> "/>
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

I want to pass the username and repcode to another page and put it in textboxes. Can anyone help me with this...I'm new in php and still learning.

Comment: [Already Asked question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13903360/is-there-a-way-to-pass-the-value-to-another-page)

Comment: if you start with php, I strongly recommand to use the `mysqli_*` object style instead of `mysql_` . See the php.net documentation for examples :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand the goal of your code, but you need to use `$_SESSION` instead of `$_POST` in the 2nd page if you want to use the values stored in SESSION:

```
<form method="get" >
  <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?> "/>
  <input type="text" name="repcode" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['repcode']; ?> "/>
</form>
```